# having structures as parameters when entered into methods in a class

Tags: matlab

My mate is trying to do this on matlab (Please excuse the terminology. I am not super sure with matlab.)
He is entering two structures which are polynomials into a class as parameters in methods but it will only accept doubles for some reason. hOW do you fix this?

```
classdef dostuff
    properties
       polyn  %not really sure what this does
    end    

    methods

        function r = plus(struct1, struct2)

            r = dostuff(addthem(struct1,struct2)); %adds the two polynomials
        end
    end
end
```

The error is *Undefined function 'dostuff' for input arguments of type 'struct'*.
How do you get the class to accept structures (polynomials) as parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `dostuff` does not have a constructor that will accept a `struct`. So the call to

```
dostuff(addthem(struct1,struct2))
```

is trying to call a constructor that doesn't exist.  You would need a constructor like

```
methods
    function obj = dostuff(mystruct)
      obj = <...>
    end
end
```